# I am not getting the error message in VScode without running it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Earlier I used to get error lines in the file name section and in the line also which contain error, but now I am not getting that. I have to run the program to know about the error in the code. Like in which line I am getting error.

As shown in the image also without running the program I am not getting the error message.
[image]

Comment: You don't get error when running an already built program, you get errors when *building* the code into a program. How do you build your program? Are you sure that the file you show will be built? Please show us your `tasks.json` file (copy-paste it as *text* into your question), and any other build-related file.

Comment: On a few unrelated notes: [Don't use `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h); Don't use global variables; Don't use so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites for any kind of learning or teaching (using them as such do more harm than being useful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Enable Your Squiggles to resolve this:

- click ctrl+shift+p
- Search c/c++: enable error squiggles
- click on it.

#### It will enable your error messages.